# Poor mouseEvent performance in Firefox on Linux

Tags: javascript, html, performance, firefox, svg

I'm attempting to create a cross-browser, high-performance SVG drawing application.

My current implementation lives on [codepen, right here.](http://codepen.io/Azeirah/pen/HoEpd)

On Google Chrome, the performance is perfect. On Firefox however, there is a problem with mouseevents being fired.

I have another drawing application that I made before, made using the HTML5 canvas. You can see the similar poor performance [here.](http://azeirah.pythonanywhere.com) The performance of the two applications is the same, so I can logically conclude it's neither SVG or html's canvas that's slowing down Firefox, I'm not using any external libraries either, it's pure js.

I'm running Ubuntu on my PC, and I don't have these performance issues on Firefox running on Windows. Is there anything I can do to fix this in JavaScript, or is this a bug.

Note: I had heard that Firefox got some performance issues from the pre-installed ubuntu packages, I removed them, so it's not that.

Answer (score 0):

This is a system specific error/bug/performance issue or you don't have the latest Firefox. I run Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit with `nvidia-331` version 331.38 graphics drivers.

Both applications run with no notable lag in Google Chrome (including all dev channels) and Firefox 29. You may want to check your Firefox version and possibly update it:

```
$firefox  --version
Mozilla Firefox 29.0
```

If it doesn't say version 29 you will need to update to make sure this isn't just for your version. Recommended installed via ppa:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ubuntu-mozilla-security/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install firefox
```

This should install the latest version of Firefox. You should also make sure to see that you have the optimal drivers for your graphics card; the open sourced once aren't always the best alternative.

Comment: I have Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit, I checked my Firefox version, the command line didn't work, so I just checked my Firefox version in the browser itself, it's at 29.0.

It's true that I don't have the most recent graphics card driver, but why should that be a problem since it works perfectly on Chrome, but not on Firefox?

I have tried before to install the official Linux AMD drivers before, but it failed miserably.

Comment: You could try turning off hardware acceleration, it is known to have caused lag and low performance on some hardware. Go to Preferences -> Advanced -> General and uncheck "Use hardware acceleration when available"...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it doesn't help, I turned off the hardware acceleration, the lag is still there.

Also, to describe the lag, drawing is perfectly smooth for the first ~4-5 seconds, then it starts getting a little choppier. After 10 or more seconds it's completely unusable. It's as if something is slowing down Firefox considerably.

Comment: So... I did some testing and it turns out that Firefox only utilizes one core of your CPU whereas Google Chrome used all cores. It is usually rather critical to have multi core processing when dealing with graphics. I did find lag occurring after a little while of painting and the application became as you said unusable after a while (in Firefox). https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=392073 (bugzilla)... Don't know the reason for it working on Windows though nor did I find a solution to your problem.